# Why am I getting an unparseable date exception?

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I am not able to parse a date using `SimpleDateFormat`. I have tried this code:

```
SimpleDateFormat fechas = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");

if (data[i].length() > 1) {
    Date f = (Date) fechas.parse(data[i]);
    System.out.println(i + " " + f);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "01/06/2015 8:20
```

"

I have the same problem again with the following code:

```
SimpleDateFormat fech = new SimpleDateFormat(" yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = (Date) fech.parse(data[i]);
System.out.println(date);
```

Which gives the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "00015/06/01  08:20:15"
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Your date strings don't match the patterns, just like the error message tells you.

Comment: Just a guess, but... "01/06/2015" does not contain a "hh:mm" part. And the 2nd thing has a) two whitespaces in the middle and b) a year of "00015", which doesn't seam right.

Comment: first is "00015/06/01 08:20:15"
and the other 
"01/06/2015  8:20:10"

Comment: (`HH` = 24 hours, `hh` = 12 hours range.)

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2):

When using `SimpleDateFormat`, the date format has to match **exactly**. In your example, you include the date, but in your date format, you also specify the hours and minutes. If your data had that text, it would work. For instance, using your first example:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class DateDemo {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    String yourData = "01/06/2015";
    String matchingData = "01/06/2015 13:00";
    SimpleDateFormat fechas = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");

    Date matchingDate = fechas.parse(matchingData);
    System.out.println("String: \"" + matchingData + "\" parses to " + matchingDate);
    Date yourDate = fechas.parse(yourData);
    System.out.println("String: \"" + yourData + "\" parses to " + yourDate);
  }
}
```

This outputs:

```
String: "01/06/2015 13:00" parses to Mon Jun 01 13:00:00 CDT 2015
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "01/06/2015"
        at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
        at Demo.main(Demo.java:14)
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

> How can I fix this problem?

Match your formatting pattern to your input.

```
LocalDateTime.parse( 
    "01/06/2015 8:20" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu H:m" )
)
.toString()
```

> 2015-06-01T08:20

## java.time

As others stated, your formatting pattern failed to match your string input.

Also, you are using troublesome old date-time classes supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

Your time-of-day hour lacks a padding zero. So you should have been using one `h` rather than two `hh`. Furthermore, a lowercase `h` means 12-hour clock, where your input seems to be 24-hour clock given the lack of an AM/PM indicator. So an uppercase `H` is in order.

```
String input = "01/06/2015 8:20" ;  // Notice the lack of a padding zero on the hour.
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu H:m" ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

> ldt.toString(): 2015-06-01T08:20

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

The pattern in your  date `String` as well as in `SimpleDateFormat()` should match :-

`SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm")` will work with `01/06/2015 2:24`

AND

`SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")` will work with `2015/06/01 08:20:15`

For complete list, see Offical Oracle Doc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dateText = "18/07/2015 05:30";        
        DateFormat fechas = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");
        try {
            Date parse = fechas.parse(dateText);
            System.out.println("Date : " + fechas.format(parse));
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }    
}
```

I do this like that source code

Comment: I yet have the same problem